# jQuery append() won't append to my element

Tags: jquery

jQuery append() doesn't work with either of my code examples below for some reason. Do you see what I'm doing wrong? I am trying to disable the submit button and append some text that says "Processing...".

Example Code 1:

```
$( "input[type='submit']" ).click( function()
{
    $( this ).attr( "disabled", "disabled" );
    $( this ).parents( "form" ).submit();
    $( this ).append( " Processing..." ); // no worky
    //$( "input[type='submit']" ).append( " Processing..." ); // no worky
});
```

Example Code 2:

```
$( "form" ).submit( function()
{
    //$( "#submit_button" ).append( " Processing..." ); // no worky
    $( this ).find( "input[type='submit']" ).prop( "disabled", "disabled" );
    $( "#submit_button" ).append( " Processing..." ); // no worky
});
```

Comment: your trying to append a text to html tab ?

Comment: input element is void element, it cannot contains any other element: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#void-element

Comment: Please see below answer do you want to similler like thator your requirement is different. please let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$( this ).after( " Processing..." );
```

`$( this ).append( " Processing..." );` actually append the text inside the input tag like this `<input type="submit">processing</input>` and it will not display in front end but if you use after it will append the text just after the input element

Comment: `after()` is what I wanted. I didn't realize `append()` added the element INSIDE the input.

Comment: @Jeff I did the same mistake ;)

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
$(this).val(" Processing..."); // if <input type="submit"> 
$(this).text(" Processing..."); // if <button type='submit'>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you are trying to change the displayed text.. since it's an input however, the displayed text is the value of the input.

```
$("input[type='submit']").val(' Processing...'); // worky
$("#submit_button").val(' Processing...'); // worky
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : $( this ).attr('value','Processing...');

Comment: you could use `.val()` instead of `.attr('value')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$( "input[type='submit']" ).click( function()
{
    $(this).attr( "disabled", "disabled" );
    $(this).parents( "form" ).submit();
    $(this).val( " Processing..." ); // no worky
    //$( "input[type='submit']" ).append( " Processing..." ); // no worky
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="prog"></div>

<input type="submit" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#submit_button").val(' Processing...');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are appending text after form submition instead of that you have to append "processing" before form submission as below

```
$( this ).append( " Processing..." ); 
$( this ).attr( "disabled", "disabled" );
$( this ).parents( "form" ).submit();
```

and i think you need to display button value as "processing" for that you have to do as follow

```
$( this ).val( " Processing..." ); 
$( this ).attr( "disabled", "disabled" );
$( this ).parents( "form" ).submit();
```

replace append with val.

Answer (score 0):

user .after() 
  would attempt to add or change nodes in the current **jQuery**

```
Check this JS Fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/548acobq/1/)
```