# Jquery UI appendTo NOT WORKING

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Im trying to use jquery ui for search bar autocomplete. When I use **div id="inputs"** autocomplete works fine, but if I use **input id="inputs"** it's not working and i need to use input in order to search works properly.

```js
(function ($) {
$.fn.googleSuggest = function(opts){
  opts = $.extend({service: 'web', secure: false}, opts);

  var services = {
    web: { client: 'hp', ds: '' },
  }, service = services[opts.service], span = $('<span>');


  opts.source = function(request, response){
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http'+(opts.secure?'s':'')+'://clients1.google.com/complete/search',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      data: {
        q: request.term,
        nolabels: 't',
        client: service.client,
        ds: service.ds
      },
      success: function(data) {
        response($.map(data[1], function(item){
          return { value: span.html(item[0]).text() };
        }));
      }
    });  
  };

  return this.each(function(){
    $(this).autocomplete(opts);
  });
}
}(jQuery));
$.each("web".split(" "), function(i, v){
  var div = $("<div>").appendTo("#inputs")
    , input = $("<input>").appendTo(div)
   input.googleSuggest({ service: v });
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="inputs"></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery append() won't append to my element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28875629/jquery-append-wont-append-to-my-element)

Answer (score 2):

`<input>` tags [can't have child elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/empty_element), so you can't `append` nodes to them.

It looks like what you're trying to append is a div, which contains another input, which you run `googleSuggest()` against:

```
var div = $("<div>").appendTo("#inputs")
  , input = $("<input>").appendTo(div)
input.googleSuggest({ service: v });
```

So it seems that you don't need to append anything. Instead, just put `googleSuggest` on the `<input>` that's already in the DOM:

```
$('#inputs').googleSuggest({ /*...*/ })
```

Comment: No trouble!  If the answer helped you you can "accept" it by clicking the checkmark near the upvote/downvote buttons.